# Dart - The getter is not identified for the type 'Object'

Tags: dart

Good day, I developed the below code to check if the values of the points are equal or not, I wrote a constructor for the sum and and received an error:

```
void main() {
  var p1 = Point(3, 4, 6);
  var p2 = Point(3, 5, 7);
  var p3 = p1 + p2;
  print(p3.toString());
  if (p1 == p2) {
    print("they are equal");
  } else {
    print(false);
  }
}

class Point {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;
  Point([this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.z = 0]);

  Point operator +(Point p) =>
    Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y, this.z + p.z);

  @override
  bool operator ==(p) {
    return this.x == p.x && this.y == p.y && this.z == p.z; //error is here
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "x:$x y:$y z:$z";
  }
}
```

and the error is:

```
The getter 'x' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
The getter 'y' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
The getter 'z' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing is that **p** parameter in equals operator is of type Object, which does not have x,y,z properties. To make it right you first need to check if **p** is Point. If not - then equals will be false. After the check type of **p** will be auto-promoted to **Point** so it will further work:

```dart
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object p) {
    if(p is! Point) {
      return false;
    }
    
    return this.x == p.x && this.y == p.y && this.z == p.z; //error is here
  }
```